# Correct way of using drop() to delete Saturday rows from panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the panda dataframe in python below.

```
full_name  serial  Date_YMD        prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    20200922    12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    20200923    12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200924    12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200925    12885.50  12984.25   62295.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200926    12880.00  13000.00   14224.0
```

I want to delete all the rows with `Date_YMD` containing Saturdays.

The final dataframe will look like this;

```
 full_name  serial  Date_YMD        prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    20200922    12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    20200923    12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200924    12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200925    12885.50  12984.25   62295.0
```

To find out whether a row is a Saturday, here is the code;

```
df['Date_YMD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['Date_YMD'].dt.dayofweek.eq(5)
```

To drop a row, I believe the `drop()` function is the right one to use. If there are better options, please advise.

The problem is how do I apply `drop()` after finding out the Saturday rows. I am open to other methods besides using `drop()` as long as it solves the problem.

I am using python 3.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just extract `day of the week` using `strftime` and filter out non Saturdays.

```
 df= df[~pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime("%A").isin(['Saturday'])]
```

or convert days to numbers and drop any that is not equal to 6

```
df=df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime("%w")!='6']

full_name serial  Date_YMD     prc1      prc2   volume
0  bottle_a   AX80  20200922  12874.5  12927.75  61023.0
1  bottle_a   AX80  20200923  12878.5  12926.75  61023.0
2  bottle_a   AX80  20200924  12872.5  12928.75  61023.0
3  bottle_a   AX80  20200925  12885.5  12984.25  62295.0
```

Comment: What about `print(df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime("%w")!='5'])` It perfectly works for me. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Found the reason. Haha. Please edit your code to do this `df = df[~pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime("%A").isin(['Saturday'])]`
You need to assign the result to `df`

Comment: Perfect answer. Tested to be working. I've marked it as correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Detected bug on code. Should be 6, not 5 in the line df=df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime("%w")!='6']
Please edit if you agree for perfect answer.